# ¿Cuál es el origen y área de uso de "cafisho"?

Tags: etimología, diferencias-regionales, sustantivos, uruguay

En el Diccionario de la lengua el lema [***cafisho***](https://dle.rae.es/cafisho) aparece como:

> Etim. disc.
>
> 1. m. *Ur*. proxeneta.

Entiendo que aparece en cursiva porque su ortografía no se corresponde con la española (como en el caso de  *sushi* o *geisha*), pero ¿cuál es esa "etimología discutida" que indica el DLE?
¿Y sólo se utiliza "cafisho" en Uruguay, como indica el DLE (tengo la idea de que tambien se utiliza en otros paises de Hispanoamérica, pero no estoy seguro)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el *Diccionario de americanismos* se recoge su uso en otros países:

> **[cafishio](https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=cafisho)**.
>
> I. 1. m. *Co, Bo, Ar, Ur.* Proxeneta. pop ^ desp. (**cafisho**; **cafisio**; **cafiso**).

Es decir, se usa en Colombia, Bolivia, Argentina y Uruguay. En el fichero general se recoge como palabra del lunfardo, con el significado de "rufián". Se advierten además algunas variantes, como se ve en la definición arriba. De la palabra hay documentación al menos desde la década de 1960. Véase el siguiente ejemplo:

> *Pero, claro, el gerente no iba a hacer trabajar extra al macho de la Valverde sin adornarle el castigo con el trabajo extra de algún inocente. Esta vez el inocente fui yo. Paciencia. Estoy deseando que la Valverde se aburra de ese cafisho.*
>
> Mario Benedetti, "La tregua", 1960 (Uruguay).

En cuanto a su etimología, se han propuesto las siguientes, según las fichas del fichero general de la RAE.

- Abreviatura de *[canflinflero](https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=canflinflero)*.
- Procedencia del italiano a través de *[cafiche](https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=cafiche)*, palabra con significado similar y de uso en más países (aunque obsoleta en algunos de ellos). En otra ficha encuentro que *cafiche* vendría del genovés *cafusci* 'hombre de color'.
- Procedencia del portugués brasileño (no se especifica la palabra origen).

Comment: Aunque la referencia diga que se usa en Colombia nunca la he oído. Si viene del lunfardo puede ser que haya llegado a Colombia a través de las letras de algún tango pero nunca se hizo popular. Yo realmente discutiría la validez de lo que dice el Diccionario de americanismos

Comment: Parece que en Chile usan "cafiche"

Comment: En Perú se usa "caficho"